# Nexus 6 defaults to Call screen upon unlock

Tags: root-access, home-screen, nexus-6

Is the Nexus 6 supposed to default to the Call screen every time I unlock my phone? I get tired of unlocking my phone, and hitting the Home button every time. I want to unlock my phone and get the Home screen....anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swipe from left to right (a common mistake in users new to Lollipop) the phone opens the dialer, much like if you swipe from right to left, you open the camera. If you swipe from bottom to top, this unlocks the phone without taking you to either.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing, really appreciate it...feel like an idiot. I have my phone rooted with custom bootloader and ROM and i can't figure this out lol